# Coding multiple modules from multiple git repos with different release cycles in IntelliJ / Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, intellij-idea

I'm working on a project which has 4 modules each in its own git repo and with its own release cycle:

- parent-pom
- lib1
- lib2
- server1

There is also another project, say "server2" which also depends on lib1 and lib2 and inherits the parent pom.

I have them set up in Maven and Teamcity, with release and snapshot artifact repos, but I'm trying to work out how to configure my environment in IntelliJ so that it builds them all together locally on my workstation.

I don't want to do git pushes or mvn deploys every time I change a version in the parent pom or a parameter on the library API.

The parent pom and the libraries are shared by another project, which is why they have separate git repos and release cycles, so that the other project is not constrained by activity on this project.

I want both IntelliJ to pick up, compile and run the latest code changes I make locally, e.g. when running the REST server, and simultaneously I want maven to handle the local changes when I run mvn tasks.

I used the mvn `relativePath` short-cut in the modules to point to the parent-pom like so:

```
    <relativePath>../shared-parent-pom</relativePath>
```

I've created an aggregator project for server1 like this in its own directory here:

```bash
/workspace/parent-pom
/workspace/lib1
/workspace/lib2
/workspace/server1
/workspace/aggregator-pom
```

like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
        http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.me.stuff</groupId>
    <artifactId>aggregator</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>../shared-parent-pom</module>
        <module>../gem-utilities</module>
        <module>../gem-security</module>
        <module>../tardis</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

This works OK with for `test` and `package`, but when I run some plugins, e.g. the `dependency` plugin:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

I see that Maven is going to the repos to try to download the lib1 snapshot that lib2 is dependent on, and failing:

```
C:\dev\tools\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\dev\workspace\aggregator -Dmaven.home=C:\IntelliJ-2017.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3 -Dclassworlds.conf=C:\IntelliJ-2017.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf -javaagent:C:\IntelliJ-2017.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=62781:C:\IntelliJ-2017.1\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\IntelliJ-2017.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2017.1.4 -s C:\Users\adam\.m2\settings.xml dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] lib1
[INFO] lib2
[INFO] server
[INFO] aggregator
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building lib1 1.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ lib1 ---
[INFO] com.me.stuff:lib1:jar:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.0.0-M4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.0.0-M2:test
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.0.0-M4:test
[INFO] +- org.lots-of-stuff:lots-of-stuff:jar:1.0.0:test                                                                     
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building lib2 1.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://my.artifactory.repo:8088/artifactory/snapshot-local/com/me/stuff/lib1/1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://my.artifactory.repo:8088/artifactory/snapshot-local/com/me/stuff/lib1/1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/lib1-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] lib1 ............................................... SUCCESS [  2.612 s]
[INFO] lib2 ............................................... FAILURE [  2.378 s]
[INFO] server ............................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] aggregator ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.804 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-30T14:26:32+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 29M/275M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project lib2: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.me.stuff:lib2:jar:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.me.stuff:lib1:jar:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT in local-snapshots (http://my.artifactory.repo:8088/artifactory/snapshot-local) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

How do I tell maven not to try to download repos but to act from the locally compiled source code?

Ideally if anyone is doing this in Eclipse, I prefer a solution that works there as well as IntelliJ and on the cmd line.

Comment: Make them separate project no aggregator separate git repos don't use submodules/subtrees for that. ? The other question is: Does server use lib1/lib2 only or lib1/lib2 used by other projects as well?

Comment: In IntelliJ you could add each project as a "Module" (see File -> New -> Module).